# Django Enumerate my related many to many objects

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have those models:

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, related_name = 'questions')
```

Im interested to have a property where it returns the index value for the related quiz.

So when i do like this in my views:

```py
def view_quiz(request,slug):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(name = slug)
    questions = quiz.questions.all()
    return render(request = request, template_name = 'main/quiz.html', context = {'quiz': quiz,'questions': questions})
```

I would be able **also** to access the index of the question.

I was thinking to create a property to question model like this:

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, related_name = 'options',default = None)

    @property
    def question_number(self):
        return 'index of the related quiz'
```

But i could not figure out the code for that property so it would return the index of the related questions.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this would be to inject each index into the questions returned by the queryset. This should be a model method on the `Quiz`, since two quizzes could share the same `Question` objects.

***Note:*** The index of the question is order dependent, and your `quiz.questions.all()` queryset has unstable ordering right now – the database won't necessarily return the questions in the same order each time. To force stable ordering, I'm going to assume that the `Question` instances are ordered by `name`.

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
    ...

    def ordered_questions(self):
        questions = self.questions.order_by("name")

        # You can change to zero based indexing using `start=0`
        for index, question in enumerate(questions, start=1):
            question.index = index  # Inject the index into the question

            # Use a yield statement here to keep the queryset lazy and efficient.
            yield question
```

Then wherever you need to access each question's index, you can use the `quiz.ordered_questions()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.
But why i have to make another iterator to define one more property? It works for me , just feels like im doing too much iterating work here to accomplish the task

Comment: At the first step i assigned it to a variable in my views and passed as context.
This did not work well.
After working through i understood totally the logic of it.
Thank You!